# Trying to edit a posed mesh for shape keys. How do I get the verts to follow the mouse?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, vertices

I'm trying to edit a posed mesh in edit mode. I have On Cage and Edit Mode on in the Armature modifier, but when I try to move the verts, they do not follow the mouse, instead they move in different directions.

Comment: Do you have a mirror modifier on the model ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that would cause the problem I'm experiencing. My problem is if I have the armature posed 90 degrees from its original position, the verts would move left and right while my mouse is moving up and down.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. The answer is Blender just does this some times. I made a new project, and the problem just doesn't exist there.

Comment: Nvm, replicated and found the problem. It was caused by having Basis checked in ShapeKeys.

Comment: Alright. Found the problem part 2. Yes, the mirror modifier does have to do with it.